# AttributeError: 'str' object attribute 'format' is read-only

Tags: python, formatting

I'm trying to practice the format method as following:

```
Drinks = '{0},{1},{2}'
s = Drinks.format = ('coke', 'pepsi', 'miranda')
print(s)
```

However I get this error:

> s = Drinks.format = ('coke', 'pepsi', 'miranda') AttributeError: 'str'
> object attribute 'format' is read-only

Answer (score 1):

`Drink.format` is a function, you don't assign values to it, you simply call it (with parenthesis rather than an equal sign):

```py
s = Drinks.format('coke', 'pepsi', 'miranda')
```